# Instrumenting flows with logging information

Tags: visual-workflow

Combining the Lightning Flow builder and the process builder it is possible to build complex automation including:

- invoking processes from other processes through invokeable processes
- invoking flows from processes
- invoking flows from flows

Sometimes, the business logic and the choices can become sophisticated and understanding what happened, if you have a bug in production, it becomes really complicated.

What are the best practices to make troubleshooting of non trivial flow and processes possible?